# Hilbert Transform matches signal rather than envelope

Tags: hilbert-transform, envelope, interference

I have an interferogram of a white LED. I am trying to extract the envelope of the signal.
[image]

Shown is the interferogram, and the absolute value of the Hilbert Transform of the interferogram. I used `scipy.signal.hilbert` to find the Hilbert Transform. I am wondering why the Hilbert Transform simply matches the curve rather than finding its envelope? Is it due to the nature of my signal? I have also attempted a cubic spline, producing the same result.

```py
    from scipy import signal
    yy_env = np.abs(signal.hilbert(yy))
```

Comment: Well, to answer that question, have you tried on a different signal? Maybe try reproducing [the documentation example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html)?

Comment: The DC offset makes your signal its own envelope.

Comment: I don’t know why but the phrasing of this comment is very funny to me.